# Autocomplete ComboBox only displays the first letter when I try and type in it

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

Having trouble with WinForms c# program that polls the google places API.

For some reason, my combobox only displays the first letter of what I type. As soon as I type in a letter, it deletes the old letter and replaces it with the new letter.

Please help me. Here is the code that I am using.

```
var request = new PlacesAutoCompleteRequest
{
    Key = "Not Telling",
    Input = comboBoxStreetAddress.Text,
    Sensor = true
};

var response = GooglePlaces.AutoComplete.Query(request);
var results = response.Predictions.ToArray();

AutoCompleteStringCollection array = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

for (int x = 0; x < results.Count(); x++)
{
    array.Add(results[x].Description);
}

comboBoxStreetAddress.AutoCompleteCustomSource = array;
```

Comment: There isn't enough code here to help you diagnose your problem.  Do you have any other methods attached to your combobox?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your problem might be elsewhere. It sorta sounds like your combo box is regaining focus each time you type a letter.